# Can't assign the item in _ArrayProtocol

Tags: swift3, swift-extensions

Hi I'm trying to retrieve data by using ParseLiveQuery

My problem is...I can't assign the item in Array..

```
import Foundation
import Parse
import ParseLiveQuery

extension _ArrayProtocol where Iterator.Element == PFObject {
    mutating func updateWithEvent(event: Event<PFObject>) {
        switch event {
        case .created(let object):
                append(object)
        case .entered(let object):
                append(object)
        case .deleted(let object):
            if let index = index(of: object) {
                remove(at: index)
            }
        case .left(let object):
            if let index = index(of: object) {
                remove(at: index)
            }
        case .updated(let object):
            if let index = index(of: object) {
                //I got an error : Cannot assign through subscript: subscript is get-only
                self[index] = object

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is problem

```
 case .updated(let object):
                if let index = index(of: object) {
                    //I got an error : Cannot assign through subscript: subscript is get-only
                    self[index] = object

                }
            }
```

Anyone know about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should be careful working with internal types and protocols. The underscore prefixing the protocol name (`_ArrayProtocol`) tells us just this; that it's an internal protocol, meaning it may be prompt for changes without warning in future Swift updates (since developers using Swift should not rely on direct/explicit usage on an internal protocol).

> ```
> internal protocol _ArrayProtocol: RangeReplaceableCollection, ...
> ```

From [swift/stdlib/public/core/ArrayType.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/ArrayType.swift).

---

Now, as for your error, the error message is quite telling

> Cannot assign through `subscript`: `subscript` is get-only

I.e., `subscript` for `_ArrayProtocol` has no available setter (e.g. via a default implementation: since you're using `_ArrayProtocol` as a type itself in your extension). It does have setter for `subscript` blueprinted, but there exists no default implementation of it, whereas a default implementation for the getter is available from `RangeReplaceableCollection`.

So for this particular case, if you want to replace an `Element` of `self` at `index`, you could e.g. make use of the mutating [`replaceSubRange(_:, with:)` method of `RangeReplaceableCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/rangereplaceablecollection/1786694-replacesubrange) accessible to types conforming to `_ArrayProtocol`, as the protocol itself conforms to `RangeReplaceableCollection`:

```
replaceSubrange(index...index, with: [object])
```

If we for a minute leave the subject of the inappropriateness of working directly with an internal protocol, we can construct an example implementing this fix, an example that can actually be be verified (in contrast to the one you've supplied in your question ...).

```
enum Foo {
    case created(Int)
    case entered(Int)
    case deleted(Int)
    case left(Int)
    case updated(Int)
}

// do not work directly with this _internal_ protocol!!
extension _ArrayProtocol where Iterator.Element == Int {
    mutating func updateWithEvent(event: Foo) {
        switch event {
        case .created(let object):
            append(object)
        case .entered(let object):
            append(object)
        case .deleted(let object):
            if let index = index(of: object) {
                remove(at: index)
            }
        case .left(let object):
            if let index = index(of: object) {
                remove(at: index)
            }
        case .updated(let object):
            if let index = index(of: object) {  
                replaceSubrange(index...index, with: [object])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But then again, you shouldn't implement such an extension to an internal protocol. Consider instead to implement the extension to public type/protocol, e.g. as an extension to `Array` constrained to `Element`'s that conform to `Equatable`:

```
enum Foo<T> {
    case created(T)
    case entered(T)
    case deleted(T)
    case left(T)
    case updated(T)
}

extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    mutating func updateWithEvent(event: Foo<Element>) {
        switch event {
        case .created(let object):
            append(object)
        case .entered(let object):
            append(object)
        case .deleted(let object):
            if let index = index(of: object) {
                remove(at: index)
            }
        case .left(let object):
            if let index = index(of: object) {
                remove(at: index)
            }
        case .updated(let object):
            if let index = index(of: object) {
                self[index] = object
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note here that in contrast to working with concrete types of the internal `_ArrayProtocol` (as in your own extension, usage of `self`), which have no available setter for `subscript`, `Array`, on the other, [does](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Arrays.swift.gyb#L738), which means you can apply your original simple element replacement `self[index] = object` when the extension is applied to `Array`.

Comment: @sungwookbaek happy to help.

Comment: _ArrayProtocol is no longer publicly visible in Siwft 3.1, but you can use same-type requirements now (which simplifies things): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43338557/does-arraytype-or-arrayprotocol-not-available-in-swift-3-1.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for the prompt, will update the answer when I get the time!