# Does _ArrayType or _ArrayProtocol not available in Swift 3.1?

Tags: swift, extension-methods, swift3

I was using `_ArrayType` in my project when I was running on swift 2.1. I upgraded to swift 3.0.2 (Xcode 8.2.1) last week and I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708106/where-did-arraytype-go-in-swift-3) that `_ArrayType` is changed to `_ArrayProtocol` and it was working well.

Today I upgraded my Xcode to 8.3.1, and it gives me error:
`Use of undeclared type '_ArrayProtocol'`. Here is my code:

```
extension _ArrayProtocol where Iterator.Element == UInt8 {
    static func stringValue(_ array: [UInt8]) -> String {
        return String(cString: array)
    }
}
```

What's wrong now? Why _ArrayProtocol is undeclared in swift 3.1 while it was working in swift 3.0.2.

Also when I look here [in git](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/ArrayType.swift) I see _ArrayProtocol available. 
Than I looked into [Swift 2.1 docs](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.1/) I am able to see '_ArrayType' in protocol listing but in Swift [3.0](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/)/[3.1](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.1/) docs I am not able to see `_ArrayProtocol`.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40691327/cant-assign-the-item-in-arrayprotocol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type names starting with an underscore should always treated as internal.
In Swift 3.1, it is marked as `internal` in the source code and therefore
not publicly visible.

Using `_ArrayProtocol` was a *workaround* in earlier Swift versions where
you could not define an `Array` extension with a "same type" requirement.
This is now possible as of Swift 3.1, as described in the 
[Xcode 8.3 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW160):

> Constrained extensions allow same-type constraints between generic parameters and concrete types. [(SR-1009)](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1009)

Using the internal protocol is therefore not necessary anymore,
and you can simply define

```
extension Array where Element == UInt8 {

}
```

But note that your `static func stringValue()` does not need any
restriction of the element type. What you perhaps intended is to
define an *instance method* like this:

```
extension Array where Element == UInt8 {

    func stringValue() -> String {
        return String(cString: self)
    }

}

print([65, 66, 67, 0].stringValue()) // ABC
```

Also note that `String(cString:)` expects a *null-terminated* sequence
of UTF-8 bytes.